# Returning Char Pointer Without Heap

Tags: c++, pointers, std, cstring, stdstring

I was working on a program and I noticed something that didn't really make a lot of sense to me. `std::string` has a function called `c_str()` which returns a C-style string (NULL-terminated) representation of the `std::string` object. What does not make sense to me is how the `c_str()` function can return a `const char *` without allocating it to the heap. The function seemingly returns the char array on the stack.

I have always thought a function could only return a valid pointer if the value it pointed to was allocated on the heap using a function like `malloc()` or `calloc()`.

How can `c_str()` return the string without using the heap and could I somehow mimic this same behavior in my own code?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: See here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596945/ownership-of-pointer-returned-by-c-str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers can point to any variable, whether on the heap or stack. `c_str` returns a pointer to the string object's internal buffer. Usually this is on the heap, however some compilers, at their discretion, may place the data of small strings on the stack instead. How do you know, though, that the returned pointer is on the stack and not the heap?

I'm not sure what exactly you want to mimic in your own code.

Comment: Well I do not know whether it is truly on the stack or on the heap, however, I assumed the stack because you do not need to free the returned variable. That said, thank you for the information. I'll have to read up on internal buffers. What I was hoping to mimic is returning pointers to objects without having to malloc them or declare them as `new`.

Comment: The string object `new`s the data internally and its destructor will `delete` the data when it the string object goes out of scope automatically. `c_str` is not returning "new" data, but only letting you take a peek at data which already existed.

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes more sense. So, to simplify, would this be similar to a garbage-collector system? (Limited, of course, to only the internal buffer.)

Comment: Yes, in a way. Modern C++ reduces the need of manual memory management such as `new` and `malloc` by using standard containers and smart pointers. This results in safer code which doesn't leak memory.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer returned by `c_str()` is actually an internal pointer into the memory of the buffer of the string (which has already been allocated on the heap). That's way it doesn't have to allocate any (new) memory. The memory has already been allocated and is how the string object stores its data.

That's why the pointer returned by `c_str()` is [invalid after modifying the string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str): since it's pointing to an internal buffer, that buffer may no longer be valid after the manipulation.

> The pointer obtained from c_str() may be invalidated by:
>
> - Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
> - Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and rend().

Note that since C++11, `c_str()` and [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) perform the same function, and it works similar to how `std::vector`'s [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and extra information. That clarifies a lot of the confusion I was having.

Comment: `(which has already been allocated on the heap)`  Maybe not, depending on whether the std::string is using short string optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function returning a pointer to something not no the heap or stack:

```
char const * Hello(void)
{
  static const char hello_text[] = "Hello";
  return &hello_text[0];
}
```

Because the variable was declared as `static`, the variable will exist after the execution leaves the function.  Therefore, return a pointer to this value is perfectly valid.